# Is there any Tor's network technical details paper?

Tags: protocol

I'm looking for technical  details of tor's infrastructure.
I did a little search but couldn't find anything special except https://www.torproject.org/about/overview.html.en which is not very in detail

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can find Tor's design document and actual [specifications on the documentations page](https://www.torproject.org/docs/documentation.html.en#DesignDoc), like the [main specification](https://gitweb.torproject.org/torspec.git?a=blob_plain;hb=HEAD;f=tor-spec.txt) , the [dir specification](https://gitweb.torproject.org/torspec.git?a=blob_plain;hb=HEAD;f=dir-spec.txt) and others.

Comment: thank you,these documentation are like RFCs. takes long time to read them :D

Answer (score 5):

Tech specs are hosted in git repositories, along with other Tor projects:
https://gitweb.torproject.org

The specs repo:
https://gitweb.torproject.org/torspec.git/tree

The Tor Protocol Specification:
https://gitweb.torproject.org/torspec.git/blob/HEAD:/tor-spec.txt